# Apps Script Triggers

Tags: google-apps-script

With thanks to Andrew Roberts, commenting on my question [Library function accessed as timed trigger DriveApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49109344/library-function-accessed-as-timed-trigger-driveapp) I now understand that triggers are visible only to the user who created them.  Two users (User A and User B) have split the task of adding the same timed trigger scripts to a large number of spreadsheet objects.  Users A and B are interchangeable members of a team.  Unfortunately User A can't see triggers established by User B and vice versa.  This makes management of triggers somewhat challenging.   My questions are:

1. Is there really no way that users in a multi-user team can see all
   triggers created by all other users in the team?
2. What happens when User A leaves the organisation?  Will the
   spreadsheets that received User A's triggers just lose the
   functionality provided by those triggers?

Comment: Since you are programmatically installing triggers, you can use [document Properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getDocumentProperties()) to save `key:value` pair each time a trigger is created by a user. This property can be accessed by all users of the document, which can be used to prevent creating multiple triggers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short answer

If you need that your team manages installable triggers collaboratively then create an account specifically to manage them an other project assets that could not be transferred between accounts.

## Extended answer

> Is there really no way that users in a multi-user team can see all
>   triggers created by all other users in the team?

Unfortunately there is no way.

> What happens when User A leaves the organisation? Will the spreadsheets that received User A's triggers just lose the functionality provided by those triggers?

It depends on the account type and the leaving user goodwill.

The triggers will work until someone using the account who created the installable triggers delete them and if this account is the spreadsheet owner they could be the only one able to transfer its ownership to another user from the same domain.

- If you are using consumer accounts the only way to transfer one account from one user to another is by given knowing the password and "being nice". If the other developer knows all the account information they could reset the password.
- If you are using G Suite accounts ask the G Suite Administrator to reset the password.

## References

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/collaborating#collaborating_with_team_drives

> **Collaborating and triggers**
>
> When you collaborate on a project, any [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) that you create are not shared with those who
>   have access to your project. If you need to have a consistent trigger
>   setup for all collaborators, you can use the [Script service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app) to create
>   triggers programmatically, at run time. For more information, see
>   [Managing Triggers Programmatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/managing_triggers_programmatically).

Comment: Thank you Rubén for this very full answer.